# Python 2.7, arcpy: import data from txt file into empty attribute table.

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy, arcgis-server

I have a shapefile (Fireincidents) that currently does not have any data. I want to populate the feature with data from a text file (north_america_fires). The text file contains the lat, long, and confidence of each fire. I've created a new insert cursor to insert new roles. I've also started a for loop to loop through each of the rows in the text file. I am having trouble identifying a method to populate the rows in the point class object. I believe I have to create a list that the data from the text file can be appended to then somehow insert that list of data into the attribute table.

My current code:

```
try:

    work = raw_input("Enter the full path of WildlandFires.mdb: ") 
    arcpy.env.workspace = work
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    iFile = raw_input("Enter the full path of wildfire text file: ")

    fields = ["SHAPE@", "CONFIDENCEVALUE"]
    cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("FireIncidents", fields)

    f = open(iFile, 'r')
    lstFires = f.readlines()

    cntr = 0

    for fire in lstFires:  
        if 'Latitude' in fire: 
            continue
        row = line.split(',')
        lstValues = []
        latitude = row[0].strip() 
        longitude = row[1].strip()
        confid = row[2].strip()
        pnt = arcpy.CreateObject("Point")
        lstValues.append(pnt)


    f.close()

except Exception as e:
    print "Error: " + str(e)
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
    arcpy.AddError(e)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please give us sample of the format of text file.You said "I have a shapefile (Fireincidents) that currently does not have any data" what it means? does it have reference to real world i mean correct lat and long?

Answer (score 0):

I just identified the issue. It does have correct lat and long coordinates. Thank you for responding.